# Ruby syntax error, unexpected tIVAR, expecting end-of-input

Tags: ruby, syntax-error

```
Getting this when running program
```

customerbill.rb:28: syntax error, unexpected tIVAR, expecting end-of-input. I am trying to calculate a restaurant check in ruby.

```
class CustomerBill


class Bill < CustomerBill
  def initalize (burgers, drinks, subtotal)
   @burgers  = 6.95 * 5
   @drinks   = 1.75 * 4
   @meal = @burgers + @drinks 
   @totalBill = @meal + @taxAmount + @tipAmount
end
```

end

```
class CustomerTax < CustomerBill
  def initalize (tax, taxAmount, totalWithTax)
  @tax          = 0.0825
  @taxAmount    = @meal * @tax
  @totalWithTax = @meal + @tax
end
```

end

```
class CustomerTip
 def initalize (tipRate, tipAmount)
 @tipRate   = 0.15
 @tipAmount = @totalWithTax * @tipRate
end
```

end

```
puts "Total meal charge #{@meal}"
puts "Tax amount  #{@taxAmount}"
puts "Tip amount  #{@tipAmount}"
puts "Total bill  #{@totalBill}"
```

Comment: It would be super if you could reformat this so that the proper things are marked as code. :)  Also, if this is the actual code, there are an awful lot of ends in there. :)

Comment: it's really not clear what you are trying to do. You definitely have some issues with end statements, but it more than that.  For example do you really want the bill class to be defined inside CustomerBill?

Comment: @DavidHoelzer It's hard to tell from the formatting, but there are actually not enough _ends_ there.

Comment: @wayneConrad Is that it?  I really can't tell.  It was way to hard to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in heading_to_tahiti's answer you have a missing end statement, but in addition you are totally misunderstanding the use of classes in ruby.  What you are trying to do is really just this:

```
burgers  = 6.95 * 5
drinks   = 1.75 * 4
meal = burgers + drinks
tax          = 0.0825
taxAmount    = meal * tax
totalWithTax = meal + taxAmount
tipRate   = 0.15
tipAmount = totalWithTax * tipRate
totalBill = meal + taxAmount + tipAmount



puts "Total meal charge #{meal}"
puts "Tax amount  #{taxAmount}"
puts "Tip amount  #{tipAmount}"
puts "Total bill  #{totalBill}"
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I need to do. I was under the assumption this had to be put into class. Thanks your solution resolved  this issue for me.

Comment: @user3905353. You just removed my answer from being the correct one to this one.  As nPn solution does yield a result it does not directly address the syntax error that is at the root of your question, which was a "syntax expecting end-of-input" error.  Which I immediately provided the correct answer for you.  After solving your question you then commented on my answer with a separate issue you had, with a variable not being initialized, which I also addressed.

Comment: @user3905353 - Just wanted to add a little more context to my previous comment.  SO is designed to help solve programming problems and build a library of answers to help solve them.  In this instance the problem you posted how to solve "syntax error, unexpected tIVAR, expecting end-of-input" is solved by adding the missing "end"statements.  Other novice programmers who search SO for similar problems will not be able to solve it by simply removing class and method definitions as this solution dictates.  This simply is not a real world solution to the problem you posted.

Answer (score 1):

**You are missing your end statement's** which close your definitions, which is why the error states "expecting end-of-input". To fix close all definitions, methods, classes, etc with end statements, i.e.

```
class Bill < CustomerBill

   def initalize (burgers, drinks, subtotal)
      @burgers  = 6.95 * 5
      @drinks   = 1.75 * 4
      @meal = @burgers + @drinks 
      @totalBill = @meal + @taxAmount + @tipAmount
   end

end
```

Comment: Thank you everyone. I was to clear the error by fixing the end statements. Now my strings are printing but the instance variables are not showing. puts "Total meal charge #{@meal} "              
    puts "Tax amount   #@taxAmount"
    puts "Tip amount  #@tipAmount"
    puts "Total bill #{@totalBill}"

Comment: That is another question and separate problem.  Please mark my answer as the correct answer to your question regarding your syntax error.

Comment: To address your second question, you have some major structuring issues with you code,, that you should really address.  But simply put, your variables (@tipAmount) aren't printing because they are nil, which means they are not being initialized before you call them in your code.

Comment: If you are testing this in irb, you have to declare the methods, then call the methods, which will then run the code inside your method definition, setting your variables.  Then you can access them.